# Как в одном запросе получить количество записей по параметрам из разных таблиц?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

У меня есть 3 таблицы.
Первая таблица это: **packs_global_cats** В ней есть 3 глобальные категории.  Каждая из глобальных категорий имеет свои субкатегории. Таблица с субкатегориями называется: **packs_cats**. Вот ее структура:

```
id
global_cat
name
```

Третья таблица это сами пакеты. Вот их структура:

**id
cat
name**

Вопрос.

Как мне посчитать количество субкатегорий, для конкретной глобальной категории, в которой есть пакеты? Начало запроса у меня такое:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM packs_cats WHERE global_cat = '$global_cats[id]'"
```

Данный запрос просто посчитает сколько есть субкатегорий для одной глобальной, но этот запрос не зайдет в таблицу с пакетами и не проверит существуют ли в этих субкатегориях пакеты.

Нужно как то с помощью LEFT JOIN, но я к сожалению не понимаю как. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант навскидку (возможно, не самый оптимальный по скорости):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
FROM packs_cats AS c
JOIN packs AS p ON c.id = p.cat
WHERE c.global_cat = <global_cat_id>
```

– здесь вместо `<global_cat_id>` нужно подставить ID глобальной категории.

---

P.S.: Нужен именно `JOIN`, а не `LEFT JOIN`, потому что `LEFT JOIN` выберет все категории – даже те, в которых нет пакетов.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! подошло!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Учите JOIN-ы :)